# Java: constructor variables vs variables visible at the class-level

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I've inherited code like this (coming from Python)

Q1) what's the point of having variables at the class level?
Q2) what's the point of distinguishing between "this." and not using it in constructor? In python i've always set the variables in the constructor with "this"

```
public class Schedule {
    private final String id;
    private final Clock clock;
    private final Map<String, WorkJob> workStore;             
    private Instant lastUpdatedTime;

    @Inject
    public Schedule(
            Clock clock,
            @Named ("id") String id,

    ) {
        workStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        this.clock = clock;
        this.id = id;
        this.lastUpdatedTime = clock.instant();
   }
```

for example, how come `this.lastUpdatedTime` but `workStore` is not `this.workStore`?

is it because `final` is used? then how come `this.clock` and `this.id`?

Comment: Hit first google results for java turorial

Comment: Research `Variable Scope`.

Comment: `this.` can be ommited to address class field if it is unique in given scope - aka you dont have local variable with the same name.

Comment: `this` in Java can often be optional.  And I don't see any class level variables here.  They're all instance variables and local variables (and method parameters).  In Java a "class variable" uses the `static` modifier.

Comment: I don't know enough Python to give you a full rundown of the differences, but in Java the idiom `this.id = id` is common when a method parameter and a member (in this case the instance variable) have the same name.  The `this.` refers to the instance variable, which the `id` parameter would hide (shadow).  `this` is not normally used otherwise in Java until you get to some tricky stuff with inner classes, or until you start chaining constructors.

Comment: @markspace why are there private variables outside of the constructor, public Schedule()? those are still considered instance variables, unique to its instance? that's so weird to me

Comment: I don't know how it works in Python, but in Java any variables declared inside the constructor would have local scope.  They go away at the end of the constructor.  To get a variable to stick around, you put it outside the constructor or any method.  You can start here and read a bit more of the following pages in the official tutorial, it'll explain things more clearly.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables on the class are called instance variables, meaning when you construct a new instance of `Schedule` it will have those variables that are specific to the instance.

the `this` keyword basically saying my instance, so for this example, the constructor takes a variable named `clock` and the Schedule class also has a variable named clock. So to distinguish between the two you use this keyword.

This `this.clock = clock;` set the variable clock on my instance to the value of clock passed to the constructor.

Comment: So why is there private final Clock clock? That's different from this.clock? If it is different, who is setting the value for private final Clock clock?

Comment: So `private` `final` are modifiers to that instance variable on the Schedule class. `private` means you can only access this variable from within this class. `final` means that once this variable is set you cannot change the value. `private final Clock clock` is the same variable as `this.clock`. Again you don't always need to use `this`. It has to be used here because the constructor argument is also named clock. If the const. argument was clock1 you could remove `this`

Answer (score 2):

**Q1) what's the point of having variables at the class level?**

If a variable is declared as static variable, then it is class level variable. All other variables are instance variables. Static variables are specific to class and so any instance created from a class will share this variable and can see the value of this variable. If one instance changes the value of this variable, then all other instances of this class starts seeing new value. In your example, there is no static keyword used in the declaration of variables. They all are instance variables.

**Q2) what's the point of distinguishing between "this." and not using it in constructor**

Your constructor is as below

```
public Schedule(Clock clock,String id)
```

If you observe, the parameters to the constructors are 'clock' and 'id'. And the name of the variables declared in the class are also 'clock' and 'id'.

If you just set `clock = clock` and `id = id`, the compiler wouldn't know what you mean. By calling constructor, you are creating a new instance of this class. By using 'this' keyword, you are saying that assign the 'id' from parameter to 'this' object's 'id' variable. (You are saying to assign the id from parameter to id of the instance that you are newly creating). And in the same way, this.clock = clock

In case, if your constructor is like below,

```
public Schedule(Clock clock1,String id1)
```

then you can simply set

```
clock = clock1;
id = id1;
```

As there is no confusion for the compiler, you need not use 'this' keyword.

Answer (score 1):

In Java objects are accessed by references. A reference is needed always to access instance variables (state) and instance methods (behaviour). 
Now when we invoke a instance method or state from within the constructor or instance method of the same class then the reference is `this`. This is not needed to be put explicitly. it is only needed in case a local variable has same name as  instance variable, then instance variable is distinguished by using `this`.

```
  public class Student {
        private int roll;
        private String name;
        public Student(int roll, String n){
              // we have roll as method parameter and also a private int roll, both has same name, jsing this. we can distinguish.
              this.roll = roll;
              name = n; // this.name = n; is also valid but as names do not conflict hence explicitly using this is nkt needed.
      }
}
```

Suggestion : try to read about `this` and `super` keywords. After reading about these two you can read about instance vs. `static` fields and methods.

Comment: maybe the confusion comes from python having namespace. any variables outside of constructor is visible in python and hence it is considered class variables. but i suppose in java, we enforce class variables with static. So, all those private variables are only visible to the instance of Schedule? Schedule A and Schdule B will have a different id?

Comment: hmm I am not sure of python,but in java there is a instance world (instance fields and instance methods) which belong to object , there is an instance world per object. Then we have static world (static fields and methods). This is shared by all object of a class. I suggest reading about static after understanding the instance world.

Comment: Also note that class level is often understood as static in java, so use instance variables and instance method fr your question or else you would get answers which would be correct in themselves but may be not related much to your question